# Mysql server gone away simple insert query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload video to S3 and then save it to DB, small videos are working fine they are getting saved and insterted to DB successfully but when it comes to large videos say over 10MB (which is not that large) are uploading to S3 but not saving to DB. Please suggest what is going on here. Because everything looks fine and why I'm getting MySQL server has gone away error for such simple query.

> ERROR - 2021-05-16 06:46:21 --> Query error: MySQL server has gone away - Invalid query: `` INSERT INTO `pub_upload_list` (`publisher_id`, `standard_list_id`, `subject_id`, `chapter_id`, `file_name`, `file_short_description`, `file_size`, `file_type`, `file_submission_date`, `file_attributes`, `browse_link`, `file_owner`, `upload_date_time`, `upload_by`) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 14, '01Gan001_004.mp4', 'test 12212', 19, '8', NULL, 1, 'browse', 57, '2021-05-16 06:46:21', 0) ``

**EDIT**
Here is complete table structure -

```
CREATE TABLE `pub_upload_list` (
 `upload_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `publisher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `standard_list_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `chapter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `file_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `file_short_description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `file_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `file_type` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `file_submission_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `file_attributes` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 = secured, 1 = unsecured',
 `browse_link` enum('browse','link') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `file_owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `upload_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `upload_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`upload_id`),
 KEY `file_owner` (`file_owner`),
 KEY `publisher_id` (`publisher_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `pub_upload_list_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`) REFERENCES `publishers` (`publisher_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: *why I'm getting MySQL server has gone away error for such simple query.* This can be due to the query execution time exceeds connection timeout, and connector decides that the server gone away.

Comment: @Akina But query is so simple that it should gets completed in 0.01s, I don't think query is an issue at all.

Comment: provide complete table structure - maybe there is some issue with datatypes? Look for constraints and triggers - maybe they detect or provide some data inconsistency which breaks the query? The query itself is safe.

Comment: But if query with less than 5MB video is working fine then how it can be issue with the bigger video files because query is same for all size videos.

Comment: The video itself does not interfere with the query - only its name is saved.

Comment: Here is full table structure - https://prnt.sc/130wvwp there are no triggers. Just simple table with one relation and that is also fine

Comment: Screenshots are not useful. Copy textual CREATE TABLE into the question text.

Comment: Edited question please check.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have updated structure please check and let me know.

Comment: It's quite simple. "I am trying to upload video to S3 and then save it to DB." The upload is taking so long that MySQL disconnects ("goes away"). After a long-running operation you should check that the connection is still there and reconnect if necessary. Even better, disconnect from MySQL before you run your long task and then reconnect after so it's not left hanging.